# Capitalize each word in CSS3

Tags: javascript, css

I am getting a string from database which is stored all in Uppercase format like `THIS IS TEST` but I need to present it in Capitalize format `This Is Test`

I tried to combine two text transforms lowercase and capitalize like below to get this

```
<span class="lowercase capitalize">THIS IS TEST</span>

.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

but it didn't do the work! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: You want to present your text in `Title case`. Is that right?

Comment: Not sure what the `Title case` is but I need to get the result like `This Is Test`

Comment: As to why it's not working: `.lowercase` and `.capitalize` have the same specificity, but the second is later in the source file, so the property's value for your span is `capitalize` (in browsers that understand it, browsers that don't will ignore the property in `.capitalize`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS cannot select text nodes and hence cannot detect whether a word has started.

The CSS `text-transform` property only acts on starting of the element(`capitalize`) or as a whole(`uppercase/lowercase`). But you can follow a JavaScript approach for your solution.

You can split the text after each space to detect a word and then wrap them inside a `<span>`. After that, use CSS to style each `span` tag with `text-transform: capitalize`

```js
var text = document.getElementById('text').textContent.toLowerCase(); // Convert the sentence to lowercase

var newText = document.getElementById('new-text');
var word = text.split(' '); // Split sentence into an array of words

for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) { // Access each element in word array
  newText.innerHTML += `<span class="capital">` + word[i] + ` </span>`;
}
```

```css
.capital {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span id="text">THIS IS TEST</span>
<div id="new-text"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
.example {
    text-transform:initial;
}
```

Get rid of this

```
.lowercase {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.capitalize {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

and of course change this

```
<span class="lowercase capitalize">THIS IS TEST</span>
```

to this...

```
<span class="example">THIS IS TEST</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

### Just Use this you are Done ---

Remove the space between class, like this-

```css
.lowercase-capitalize {
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div class="lowercase-capitalize">this is test</div>
```